# How to find out PCIe Maximum Payload Size in C program?

Tags: c, pci-e

is there any library or something in C lang, so I can find out Max payload size of PCIe bus ? I think BIOS should know it, is there any chance how to read from there or any ideas ?

Comment: This is not a system-wide setting; it can be different for each device. The way to get this information would have to be OS dependent. It isn't  in the C runtime library.

Answer (score 0):

You can potentially read it using the [PCI library (libpci)](https://github.com/pciutils/pciutils), as it includes functions to access the configuration space of PCI devices.